# "'version' has bad syntax" error when attemping update-initramfs with -k version

Tags: kernel, versions

I want to run the following command : 
`sudo update-initramfs -u -k version` , but i get the following error message `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-version
dpkg: warning: version 'version' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
grep: /boot/config-version: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/version
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: FATAL: version: not absolute path.
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /tmp/mkinitramfs_lO9VOS/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `man update-initramfs`, you should put a specific kernel version for `-k`
Instead of the "version" string itself.

For example, if you want to use your current kernel, it would be:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k `uname -r`
```

Since `uname -r` could print you the kernel version, it's equivlant to:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k 3.13.0-32-generic
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the string 'version' with the actual version number.

example: `sudo update-initramfs -u -k 3.5.0-23-generic`

You can use `uname -r` to get the version